# Copying/moving document sets in SP 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-set, workflow-activity

How can we copy/move document sets to a different library in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

i was also stucked with same issue few days before,but there i was moving an item from one library to another  and i think you also have to follow the same approach which i followed, here is difference lies in document set and item name but these both are same(means these both are consider as an item of in library), [try this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201270/unable-to-copy-all-documents-from-one-library-to-another/201798#201798)

Answer (score -1):

I would like to offer to consider using third party product for this.

[Plumsail Workflow Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) has [Copy DocumentSet](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/Actions/Files%20and%20Folders%20processing.html#copy-documentset) workflow action.

To know more, please check out the following blog post 
[How to copy DocumentSet to another library in SharePoint 2013/2016/Online](https://plumsail.com/blog/2016/09/how-to-copy-documentset-to-another-library-in-sharepoint-online/)

P.S.: I'm one of the developers of the product and I hope it can help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work, I just tried and it messed up my site.

Comment: Please write me directly rylov@plumsail.com I will help you to configure the solution

Comment: Does your solution maintain ID & history for documents inside document set. and is it a pure client side solution? if yes please guide us to the menthods you used (my case is SharePoint 2013 CSOM)