# unable to copy all documents from one library to another

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to copy multiple documents from one library to another using **SPD workflow2013** in which am using **REST API's** and Looping, for copying single document I   followed **[This](http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/2/19/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-to-copy-file-via-res.html)** article and it works fine for a copying single document to another library because there am passing the hard coded name of that specific item/file which is available in my document library.but here **I want to copy multiple documents and for that I used the Loop in SPD workflow along with REST API's**,here with help of Loop am reading all names of documents from my document library and simply passing this to REST API instead of hard coded name but this is not working as I want ,inside loop when am reading all documents by  calling REST API call action it gets only first item/file name and when am reading all documents by not calling REST API call action and simply log that item name variable to WF history then it is going through all items and showing these names in log history .
my workflow without Calling Rest API call action is as like below snap
[image]

 Output
[image]

 my workflow with Calling REST API call action is as like below snap 
[image]
and it's output is as like below snap
[image]

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with your REST URL. Build the REST URL in a string variable and output it to the log and then use the variable for the address. It would also be good to output the `responseCode8` variable as well to verify you got the desired response.

Comment: In your copy action you have /sites/appdev/Preparation/[%Current Item:Title%]/[%Variable: Name%] Should "Current Item Title", really be "Workflow Context: List Title"? I think it really needs to be the url of the List you want. The List Title may not be the List URL.

Comment: @OmarStewey actually am copying item to another list in which am creating the folder of that list item name so thats why am puthing this([%Current Item:Title%]/[%Variable: Name%]) in my URL

Comment: @theChrisKent i tried what you suggested but still the problem  is as it was,you can see that here(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ovbn.png)

Comment: Does it work if you copy to the root of the library? Without the item title?

Comment: i didn't get you

Comment: what i did is ,i have removed this [%Current Item:Title%] n tried but that alos not working

Answer (score 2):

Finaly Resolved the Issue,there was one small problem and that was the response after first Iteration was not proper means that was not get changed as per Iteration,Resolved the Issue by simply calling the ***call action*** same as above inside loop in which I'am iteration Item Names from Library
it's same as below snap
[image]