# Can I use a closing workflow to move a document from one library to another?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, document-library, designer-workflow

I have a list in SharePoint 2010 which has links to documents in a document library on the same SharePoint site. When the workflow closes, I want to move a copy of all the documents that are linked in the list to an archive library.

What are the commands I can use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately,** in your scenario, the SharePoint Designer can't help!

To be able to copy document to another document using SharePoint designer, you should have a workflow **on** the source document library to can (`Copy item + Then delete`) to the destination document library as shown below:

[image]

> **Note** you can use `Call HTTP Web Service` action to copy a document to another document library Using REST, but unfortunately, this action is not available in SharePoint Workflow 2010.
>
> For more details check [unable to copy all documents from one library to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201270/unable-to-copy-all-documents-from-one-library-to-another/)

---

**So in your case**, the available workaround is using `Event Reciever` to can easily control the moving process based on the document URL.

For more details check [Programmatically Copy and Move documents in Sharepoint 2010](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/04/programmatically-copy-and-move-documents-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I started thinking about this. In the closing workflow could I set an attribute on the document in the document library (like “approved” and then use a workflow in the document library to copy all approved documents?